# RTE5 using `Shell` in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shell

**Background:**

Recently, a macro I use via VBA (in Excel) to run a script has stopped working; this subroutine worked for the previous six years.  This is on a work device in which I do not have full admin privileges.  The script file is stored on a network drive which I have access to, and can open and double-click to execute.

I have read from multiple sources, each not having an answer (including here on SO), that people have begun to see RTE5 when using `Shell()`, which may be related to security settings from the administrator.

One suggestion was to use use `ShellExecute`, which I have not had luck using.

---

**Issue:**

I receive RTE5 (invalid procedure call or argument) on the line for `Shell()` within the below code.

---

**Question:**

Has anyone had this same issue and been able to resolve said issue?  Please indicate how you resolved.

---

**Code:**

```
'To open file, which previously worked:
Dim Loc As String
Loc = "Z:/filename.bat"
Call Shell(Loc, 1)

'Attempt at using ShellExecute, which gives Network Access error
Dim Loc As String
Loc = "Z:/filename.bat"
Call CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute(Loc, 1)
```

Comment: If you are unable to change your security settings you should rewrite the .bat file in VBA. There are very few things you  can't do in VBA.

Comment: @HackSlash i apologize as I hadn't thought to address that in the post.  The called .bat file is maintained by an admin relating to the 'most recent' version of a file, which includes the actual file name (the file name includes the date of versioning); this .bat is opened by multiple users.  I believe I would need to make a macro for each user, updating the name of the file in each macro when it changes.  Currently the .bat file contains a line for `start excel.exe "//path/filename.xlsb"`

Comment: Reading the file doesn't require execute permission. Just pull the name of the workbook and open it from VBA. No shell needed.

Comment: The slash in your question (`Z:/filename.bat`) probably should be a backslash. And as Cyril wrote, there is no point in calling a command file from Excel to open Excel, you could open the Excel file directly.

Comment: @FunThomas I ended up rewriting the macro to include opening the file via wildcard, after some checks for the appropriate file (so i don't have everything open in the directory, after some chatting with HackSlash).  This particular issue with the file being open is resolved, though I am still wondering if there is a workaround for the `Shell()` failing due to privileges/security that isn't "just write it all in VBA".

Comment: I'm probably not well versed enough to think of when a shell call would be appropriate... nothing is immediately coming to mind.

Comment: It is likely that permissions to execute .bat scripts on the device have changed - that's a typical type of restriction you find on corporate PCs to prevent arbitrary code from executing.